# WinPE boot disc containing files outside of ramdisk

Tags: waik

I am using WAIK for Windows 7 to create a "restore disc"

I have created a WIM image for the computer, and put it on a WinPE disc.  However, when the computer boots up, it states that it is too large for the Ramdisk.

Is there any way to put files on this disc that are NOT loaded in Ramdisk, that will just be loaded from the CD when needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to put the files in the ISO folder, as opposed to inside the WIM.